# what is the difference between "you can go first" and "you go first"

Tags: sentence-meaning, difference

What is the difference between "you can go first" and "you go first"?

If me and a friend of mine for an example ask the teacher a question at the same time which one should I use

Comment: By default, *You go first* is an [imperative] ***instruction / order*** (you ***must*** or ***should*** go first), whereas by default, *You **can** go first* grants ***permission*** (you can do this if you want to, but you don't ***have*** to). But in practice those meanings may in fact be reversed in any given context (they're just ***likely*** differences, not absolutely fixed by the specific phrasing). The idiomatic standard ***After you*** can carry either implication equally well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"You can go first."*
The word ***can*** implies that you are giving the person the option to do or not do a certain action.
*"You go first."*
Removing it implies that you are giving order or forcing someone to do something. You are not giving that person the choice of not doing it.